# Get 2D array after mask condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a question about my script and I would like your help or any idea to resolve my problem.

I have a 2D array with data and I would like divide it by an other 2D array. Up to now, it's not a problem.
But I put a condition which is : this both arrays must take account the binary mask and just take pixels = 1.

I wrote that :

```
fig10, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

# ARRAYS TAKE ACCOUNT PIXEL = 1 IN THE BINARY GRID
convolution_mask_locale_data = convolution_mask_locale[grid.T == 1]
convolution_mask_grande_data = convolution_mask_grande[grid.T == 1]

convolution_locale_data = convolution_locale[grid.T == 1]
convolution_grande_data = convolution_grande[grid.T == 1]

# FIRST STEP DIVIDE  
step1 = convolution_locale_data / convolution_mask_locale_data

fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(step1, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

# SECOND STEP DIVIDE
step2 = convolution_grande_data / convolution_mask_grande_data

fig_step2 = ax2.imshow(step2, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step2,ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

# SUBSTRACT BOTH RESULTS
S_N_map = step1 - step2

fig_S_N_map = ax3.imshow(S_N_map, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_S_N_map,ax=ax3)
ax3.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

fig10.tight_layout()        
fig10.savefig(outname10)
```

But I get a problem : at the end, I need to get the same thing as a heatmap. But when I handle my arrays with the grid.T condition, my 2D array becomes 1D array and I can't make operations.

Do you have an idea on How I can process ?
Maybe it's not totally clear and I am sorry for my very bad English.

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

The variable grid.T is a binary array (0 or 1) which indicates if I have stars in my pixel (value 1) or nothing (value 0).

[image]

The variable convolution_mask_local represents the previous grid.T which is convolved by a Gaussian. It's also a 2D array

[image]

**SOLUTION BY OliverW. :**

When I update my script with the solution given by OliverW., I obtain this :

```
fig10, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

mask = binary_mask == 0

A = np.ma.masked_array(convolution_locale, mask = mask)
B = np.ma.masked_array(convolution_mask_locale, mask = mask)

C = np.ma.masked_array(convolution_grande, mask = mask)
D = np.ma.masked_array(convolution_mask_grande, mask =mask)

step1 = A/B
step2 = C/D


fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(step1, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")


fig_step2 = ax2.imshow(step2, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step2,ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

# SUBSTRACT BOTH RESULTS
S_N_map = step1 - step2

fig_S_N_map = ax3.imshow(S_N_map, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_S_N_map,ax=ax3)
ax3.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

fig10.tight_layout()       
fig10.savefig(outname10)
```

I get these plots (the second one seems to work very good, but not the first on for an unknown reason) :

[image]

Comment: What is the variable `grid`? What is `convolution_mask_locale`? Please make your example into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliverW. Ok sorry OliverW, I edited my question in order to become clearest as possible. As I have lots of details, it's possible that I forgot something ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're interested in visualizing 2D arrays where some elements can be ignored (masked).

Fortunately, this functionality exists under numpy ([numpy's masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html)) and matplotlib can work with them as well.

Below is an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = np.random.random_integers(0,1, (3,3))  # generate some fake data
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
>>> mask = a == 0
>>> b = np.random.random_integers(0,9, a.shape) # more fake data
>>> c = np.random.random_integers(1,9, a.shape) # more fake data
>>> b
array([[9, 5, 2],
       [9, 7, 5],
       [4, 4, 2]])
>>> c
array([[4, 9, 4],
       [5, 5, 9],
       [5, 7, 3]])
>>> B = np.ma.masked_array(b, mask=mask)  # initialize a masked array
>>> C = np.ma.masked_array(c, mask=mask)
>>> B
masked_array(data =
 [[9 5 --]
 [-- 7 --]
 [4 -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> C
masked_array(data =
 [[4 9 --]
 [-- 5 --]
 [5 -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> B/C  # you can divide these 2D matrices element-wise, the mask is retained
masked_array(data =
 [[2.25 0.5555555555555556 --]
 [-- 1.4 --]
 [0.8 -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
>>> (b/c)[~mask]
array([ 2.25      ,  0.55555556,  1.4       ,  0.8       ])
```

Notice how the masked arrays, `B` and `C` retain their 2D shape, while the logically indexed array `(b/c)[~mask]` has obtained a 1D shape. That's normal and due to the way the indexing works: numpy cannot know upfront if the logically indexed array can be represented with strides (in general, it can't), so it flattens the array. Using masked arrays however, you can just continue working the way you're used to. The mask is retained between operations, and as you can see from the last two lines of code, the same values are in the 2D array.

Finally, you can visualize the masked array. Just call:

```
plt.imshow(B/C, interpolation='none')
```

and it will show you a 3x3 grid, where some values are masked (in my case, that means they're transparent, which on a white background will result in white pixels).

Comment: Your answer is very very interesting ! I understand better the process ! I am editing my question with your script. But, I don't know why just the half works fine. I post my result at the end of my question ;)

Comment: I have, in my first plot, some values which are not good (> 100). I write "new_step1 = step1[step1 < 100]" but new_step1 becomes a 1D array instead to 2D array (what I want). Do you have an idea on How process ?

Comment: @Astrolabe1993, the reason your first and third axis image are not what you expect, is because of the underlying values. Look at the scalebars ;-) When you (for ax3) subtract a small number from a huge number, you'll end up with still a huge number. So ax3 is very similar to ax1. I can't help more than that with the visual representation: you should look at how you are creating `convolution_mask_locale` and the others to see why those numbers are so huge (is that what you're expecting?).

Comment: @Astrolabe1993, regarding your comment from a few minutes ago, it is unclear to me how you want to continue, so what do you want to do with the 1D array? If you want it as a 2D array, just use a mask, as shown earlier. If you want it as a 1D array, continue explaining what you want to do with the 1D array.

Comment: Ok I added two masks for the first operation in order to mask values greater than 1 and less than 0.001. I used " np.ma.masked_greater" and " np.ma.masked_less". So I get a very good map (I assume) and now, I'm trying to fit a Gaussian over the histogram (I get error about it, but it's not about my first question). I will see with my tutor if the result is good, but to me, sounds good :) Thank you very much !